# adding to input and cloning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am trying to clone and also add values to results:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNP3r/175/

It is working so-so' on the table element.

But what I want to do is to make it work on a div element rather than table.

How can this be solve?

...Because when I do:

```
$('#mtable2 section').append($("#mtable2 section:first").clone());
```

...It clones and doubles everytime you do it....I just want to do one row like the Table's Tbody TRs...

Lastly I would like to clone it only if all forms are added...kind got it working on the else statement.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a div and append underneath with new values?

Comment: new values and some are just cloned....it works on the table...just cant get it to work if I change this into divs

Comment: yes append to top as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#irowb").click(function(){
    $('#mtable2 section:last').after($("#mtable2 section:first").clone());   
});
```

Your first problem is you do an `append` which inserts the code into the section and not after that and your second problem is you append it after each section, not only the last one

Edit:

```
 $('#mtable2 section:first').before($("#mtable2 section:last").clone());  
$("#mtable2 section:first").find("#test-a").html($('#row3').val());
$("#mtable2 section:first").find("#test-b").html($('#row4').val());
```

Comment: Yes! I think its almost there: http://jsfiddle.net/QNP3r/176/.... Am I doing something wrong that it is not adding the value though?

Comment: Yes! One more thing, how can i get the clone to always clone on top?

Comment: it is the `before` :) and don't use in this case `section:last` but `section:first`

Comment: i've updatet my answer once again, cause i had a bug in the code. if you could fix it yourself its also ok :D

Comment: Ahh awesome thanks for being generous and being more indepth...I think my last step will be adding unique ids to the clones but that will be another question to be solved

Comment: No problem :) For your id part you could just add `$("#mtable2 section:first").attr("id", "theIdYouWantTo");` at the end